# install python package to sys.path

Tags: python, package, sys.path

I am new to python3 and I want to create a package that I can import from other python script.

So I created my package and I run

> ***python3 setup.py sdist***

to create my tarball.

when I move it to another directory to untar it and then install the package with

> ***python3 setup.py install -user --prefix=***

it's fine there is no error and it install in my site-package of python and when I run python3 I can import my lib and call its function.

But when I want to import this package in a script it tell me

> **ImportError: No module named test_package.pck1.addition**

I know that I can add

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./test_package.0.1')
```

to fix it but I want to avoid that because it would mean always having to modify the path to the package when trying to use it in another script.

**So How can I import my package without modifying the sys.path. Or how can I an install my package so that my script won't need that.**

I tried a lot of installation process (using pip3, trying different option etc) nothing work as I expect it.

Comment: how you have created the package ? I want to learn it . can you share some resources and examples for this package topics

Comment: It's mainly a test so its nothing really creative I mainly followed tutorial and tried to make it my own here is the tutorial I followed : [link](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)

Comment: ya i need tutorials if you have any then please share it with me. Videos will  be appreciated

Comment: I didn't watch video so here is the tutos I used :   [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) the 6.4 part, and [link](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html) also this to install the package [link](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)

Comment: where is your package located?

Comment: before I Install it I stored it in a package_test directory and when I install it python tell me that  **Adding test-package 0.1 to easy-install.pth file** **Installed /Users/berthierhadrien/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/test_package-0.1-py3.6.egg**

Answer (score 0):

you created the python package 'toto.py'. you want to import it in the python script 'tata.py'. you write 'import toto' in the tata script and you place the file 'toto.py' in a directory contained in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Although I don't use python 2, it seems to me it is the same for python 2 and 3. Thus I'm not sure I understood the question.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but the problems is that I want it to be done on the package installation because if I give my package to someone else I don't want that person to have to put the package inside a specific directory. The thing I don't understand is that when I launch python3 I can import my package and use it but in a script it tell me that the import can be done except if I add `sys.path.append('Path To My Package')`